# How do I close a modal form right after opening it?

Tags: delphi, dialog

From my application I wish to open a dialog, which should close immediately (after a short message) under some circumstances.

I've tried this:

```
procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SomeCondition then
  begin
    ShowMessage('You can''t use this dialog right now.');
    close;
    modalresult := mrCancel;
  end;
end;
```

but the dialog remains open. I've also tried to put the code in the OnShow event, but the result is the same.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this one

```
procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('You can''t use this dialog right now.');
  PostMessage(Self.Handle,wm_close,0,0);
end;
```

Answer (score 20):

Post a WM_CLOSE message instead of calling close directly;

```
ShowMessage('You can''t use this dialog right now.');
PostMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
modalresult := mrCancel;
```

Comment: I accepted Bharat's answer, even though your answer was almost identical. Sorry. He beat you by two seconds :-)

Comment: @Svein - Here, SO shows my answer beat his with 37 seconds. But anyway it is close enough not to make a fuss about it. :-)

Comment: As Einstein said: the perception of time depends on your speed.

Comment: Voted for this answer because of mrCancel

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be easier to check the certain circumstance before the form opens, and not open it?

I can't see a reason for the form to stay open, it should disappear immediatly after clicking `OK` on the show message dialog.

The showmessage is blocking so you won't be able to close until that's OK'd (if you need to close before then you could return a different modal result (or make your own up which doesn't clash with the existing ones like mrUnavailable = 12). Then you could show the message if the ModalResult was mrunavailable.

If it is running the code and just not closing then try using `Release` instead of close.

**Edit:** if you re-using the same form in several places don't use Release unless you want to recreate the form every time! Post the close message as the others have suggested

Comment: I open the dialog from several places, and I don't want to check every place.

Comment: Then use a method that you can call from several places. Do the checks in that method and if ok, only then open the form

Answer (score 0):

You can try a timer:

- set the timer a low interval (20)
- on the OnTimer event, close the form;
- enable the timer on the FormActivate event